# How can I create a square 10x10 grid using nested for loops in Java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a 10x10 grid using for loops in Java. I'm able to create rows going up and down but not repeating.

```
            for(int i = 1; i < temperatures.length; i++) {
                temperatures[i] = (temperatures[i-1] + 12) / 2; //takes average of 12 and previous temp
            }
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            for(int y = 1; y < 9; y++) {
                g.setColor(Color.black);
                g.drawRect(10, 10, 10, 10);
                g.drawRect(10, 10, 10, 20);
                g.drawRect(10, 10, 10, 30);
                g.drawRect(10, 10, 10, 40);
                g.drawRect(10, 10, 10, 50);
                g.drawRect(10, 10, 10, 60);
                g.drawRect(10, 10, 10, 70);
                g.drawRect(10, 10, 10, 80);
                g.drawRect(10, 10, 10, 90);
                g.drawRect(10, 10, 10, 100);

                for(int x = 1; x < 9; x++) {
                g.setColor(Color.black);
                g.drawRect(10, 10, 10, 10);
                g.drawRect(10, 10, 20, 10);
                g.drawRect(10, 10, 30, 10);
                g.drawRect(10, 10, 40, 10);
                g.drawRect(10, 10, 50, 10);
                g.drawRect(10, 10, 60, 10);
                g.drawRect(10, 10, 70, 10);
                g.drawRect(10, 10, 80, 10);
                g.drawRect(10, 10, 90, 10);
                g.drawRect(10, 10, 100, 10);
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: remember to indent correctly as well, this will help with understanding your code better

Answer (score 9):

```
width=10;
height=10;    
for(x=0;x<10;x++)
{
    for(y=0;y<10;y++)
    {
        g.drawRect(x*width,y*height,width,height);
    }
}
```

Comment: I wasn't looking to make a grid, but I will do now. Thanks :D

Comment: i'd say define width and height in your answer too, given the simple nature of the question.

Answer (score 2):

My 2 cents to the previous answer:

To make sure the grid fills up the entire area, do the following:

```
int width = totalWidth / 10;
int height= totalHeight / 10;
for(int row=0;row<10;row++){
    for(int col=0;col<10;col++){
        g.drawRect(row*width,col*height,width,height);
    }
}
```